# Expectation of CauchyDistribution

Tags: bugs, probability-or-statistics, distributions

**Bug introduced in 8.0 or earlier and persisting through 13.2.0**

---

I've noticed this strange behavior and I'm wondering if it's a bug.

I define a Cauchy distribution:

```
c = CauchyDistribution[0, 1];
```

If I evaluate `Mean[c]`, I get `Indeterminate`, as expected.

If I evaluate `Expectation[x, x \[Distributed] c]`, I get `Expectation[x, x \[Distributed] CauchyDistribution[0, 1]]`. I would have expected `Indeterminate`, too, but that's ok.

However, if I evaluate `Expectation[x + y, {x \[Distributed] c, y \[Distributed] c}]`, I get `0`.

The sum of two independent Cauchy distributed random variables should be another Cauchy distributed random variable, right? Why is the expectation 0?

Comment: Another example of why I think it is best to avoid using prepackaged written up results , and go for general symbolic methods. Indeed, if you ask Mma to find the general solution, it works perfectly. Here:   `f = (1/(Pi (1 + x^2))) (1/(Pi (1 + y^2))); ` and `Integrate[(x + y)*f, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity,   Infinity}]` returns the appropriate 'does not converge' message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check that :

```
TransformedDistribution[ x + y, {x \[Distributed] CauchyDistribution[0, 1], 
                                y \[Distributed] CauchyDistribution[0, 1]}]

(* CauchyDistribution[0, 2] *)  

Expectation[z, z \[Distributed] CauchyDistribution[0, 2]]
(* Expectation[z, z \[Distributed] CauchyDistribution[0, 2]] *)

Mean[TransformedDistribution[ x + y, {x \[Distributed] c, y \[Distributed] c}]]
(* Indeterminate *)
```

Comment: So, the conclusion is it's a bug?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Yes it looks like it.

Comment: @AndyRoss can you confirm this diagnosis?

Comment: @rcollyer I was hoping for news from him too.